# How do centrifugal pumps connected in series increase head?

Tags: pumps, hydraulics

I've read that if you connect two identical centrifugal pumps one after another, the head of this system would be twice the head of a single pump. I have some difficulties understanding the processes and physics behind it. **How does the second pump increase the head if the incoming water already has the pressure, speed (or energy in general) equal to the values the pump provides?**

My current understanding goes like this.

Let's replace the first pump with an endless tank of water under the pressure *P*. If we connect the pump to the tank, the pressure will force a flow through the pump with a speed *V* (ignoring some energy loss due to the pump resistance). When we turn the pump on, the centrifugal force increases this speed which, by some hydraulics magic, ends with an increased head of a system. But if the initial speed of the flow *V* is high enough and the rotation of the impeller doesn't add much to that speed, then the pump won't add much to the head.

Comment: It will only be twice if the pumps have the same head.

Comment: @SolarMike as far as I understand it will be head_1 + head_2 whatever are the heads. Or not?

Comment: Yes, this time you have explained it better.

Comment: I've edited the question, let the pumps be identical to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Confusion comes from the question, need to make sure things are explained clearly.

Comment: @SolarMike can you explain what is unclear now? I'll be happy to improve the question.

Comment: This might be a problem if the water velocity were so high as to create a generator out of the pump, but at normal pressures & flow rates we're just adding more energy to the water.

Comment: The pumps become mechanically coupled via the fluid itself.  To what degree depends on properties of the fluid and the pumps.  If you have head vs flow curves for the pumps, you should be able to derive a resultant curve for the pumps in series.

Comment: @TigerGuy jokes aside, is it possible that after joining 100 pumps in series, the 101st would be closer to generating energy, not adding it?

Comment: @Abel am I correct to assume that the resulting system curve is more complicated than single pump curve x2?

Comment: @Usurer the second pump out of two could generate energy

Comment: It can be as complicated as all of existence. One usually makes assumptions and accepts approximations to avoid that. While having flow vs head curves can get you a resultant curve, you seem to be more interested in specific points on that curve. The key piece you are missing to reach that from just pumps is the load these pumps drive and how that reacts to pumps attempting force fluid through it (a head vs flow curve for the load itself).